# Show more than 10,000 characters in a JavaScript Alert

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript object max size limit at 10000 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927647/javascript-object-max-size-limit-at-10000-chars)

I want to check whether html source contains a specified string, but I'm only getting 10,000 characters (in alert box)

```
var str=document.documentElement.innerHTML;
if(str.indexOf("abcxyz") !== -1)
{
  alert(str);
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: It is probably a character limit on your browser's `alert()` (that isn't what your code above does though)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5927647/337315

Comment: Please 1) ask a single question 2) post code that actually reflects the problem.

Comment: @pst I'll remember it next time. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I know everyone is all eager about closing questions, but the problem here is that even though the linked question does address the question here, the subject title is so different that even a reasonable search effort won't be too likely to turn up that question.  That means that the typical user experience to find an answer to this question, then have to go to the linked issue.  That gives a poorer user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to display a huge string in alert boxes, I guess you could split it into 10,000-character chunks and display them in order. Alternatively, just use [`console.log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#consolelogging) to print it out.

> And is there a better way to detect a "onClick" event?

Better than what? JavaScript events will bubble up to the top containing element (unless some element in the chain calls `stopPropagation()`), so an easy way to detect click events would be to attach a click handler to `document.body`:

```
document.body.onclick = function() { alert('Click!'); }
```